# Application deployment in linux machine using jBoss

Tags: java, jboss

I deploy my web application to linux machine using java version "1.6.0_29" and jboss version 4.0.5

Now upgrade jboss as jboss version jboss-as-6.1.1.Final and java version "1.7.0_10"

I deployed application like "AP.war" not working says error like http 400 error

anybody suggest me.

Comment: check yr logs and post relevant messages, could be anything

Comment: in server log cant showing any error.only it shows jboss started

Comment: Is the AP.war deployed correctly? Do you see it as green?

Comment: "in server log cant showing any error.only it shows jboss started" - jboss logs plenty information about what it deploys. Do you see your war being deployed in the server log? If not you are doing something very wrong; like starting the wrong JBoss instance wrong.

Comment: ya i m deployed appliction that shows green color.The same application i m deployed another server which hav jboss 5.0that is working